# Parsing CSV file into array with comments at top

Tags: php, parsing, csv, hash, extract

Here is a template of a possible text file I might need to import into my database:

```
#NAME:"Test"
#REV:"rev1"
#PRODUCT:"product1","description1","option1"
#PRODUCT:"product2","description2","option1","option2"
"A1","key1","DALI"
"B1","key2",""
"B2","key3","option2"
"C1","key4",""
```

The first 4 lines is a new addition to the format of these files. I was importing the comma separated data itself successfully before the addition of the comment lines on top.

I was wondering if someone can provide me the most efficient way to put all the values in the comment lines into variables in PHP.

I always have a little trouble when it comes to RegEx. I'm not sure how to best grab the lines starting with a #.
Essentially, I would like to have the following data available to me:

```
$csv['name']: "Test";
$csv['rev']: "rev1";
$csv['products']: array(
    0 => array('name' => "product1", 'desc' => "description1", 'options' => "option1"),
    1 => array('name' => "product2", 'desc' => "description2", 'options' => "option1,option2"),
);
$csv['data']: The rest of the data in text file
```

There could be multiple #PRODUCTS defined, so that is why it would be nice to have an array made from those lines.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using php 5.3? If so, then you can simply read your file using fgets() and detect comments using substr($line, 0, 1). If you don't detect a #,it means it a data line, then pass it on to str_getcsv()...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To match something started with #, just use ^ at the beginning of regexp (outside of group)